JavaScript redirect to variation of filename
I have several thousand external links that take the form 'mysite/linkfile.php=a'. Unsurprisingly, they return page not found. What I want to do is create a file called 'linkfile.php=a' and use javascript to obtain the file name (they are all different), remove the '=a' part of the file name (this is consistent) and then redirect the user to 'mysite/linkfile.php'.
Something like:
<script>
    function myFunction() {
      var url = window.location.pathname; var filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
      document.getElementById("newfilename").innerHTML = filename.replace("=r", "");
      window.location='https://www.mysite/filename';
    }  
// -->
</script>

This works OK until the last line, which cannot recognise the result of `filename.replace("=r", "")` in that URL. Is this purely a syntax issue?
I'm a noobie so any help will be gratefully received.

Usually URLs are in the form filename.php?param=value. filename.php=a seems wrong.

Probably check if your web server can do mod_rewrite, and change incoming requests to bad urls to point to correct urls.

That's a really good idea James - what would the mod_rewrite look like?

You need to change your last line to use backticks and wrap filename in ${} so that the contents of the filename variable get inserted into your string.
function myFunction() {
  var url = window.location.pathname; var filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
  document.getElementById("newfilename").innerHTML = filename.replace("=r", "");
  window.location=`https://www.mysite/${filename}`;
}


Thank you Ray - that works perfectly. Attention to the backticks seems to be crucial. Thanks so much for replying to my question.
